# How to adjust team win probability based on in in game win probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, least-squares, modeling, odds

I have a formula to calculate each team's win probability based on their win rates and home court advantage. So lets say I use it to determine that team A has 45% chance to win and team B has 55% chance to win the game before it starts.

I have another model which calculates the mid-game win probability of two equal (.500) teams based on the games score and time remaining. So lets say based on the game situation it determines that the first team wins 30% and the other 70% accordingly.

My question is how should I combine the pre game win probability based on team strength with the in game probability based on the current game state? Averaging them together doesn't seem to work because if, for example, we have team with a pregame win probability of say 30%, as soon as the game starts the in game probability would be 50% due to tie game therefore if we average them together their real time win probability would be 40%. But common sense says that if the game just started and it's tied their win probability should be the same as it was pregame. I should emphasize that my in game probability model already takes into account the time remaining, so a deficit in 4th quarter will have a bigger impact on it than the same deficit in the 1st quarter.

Comment: Ideally you would use a single comprehensive model that is conditional on pre-game and current game state. Short of that, a simple averaging scheme would weight the two probabilities by the proportion of game remaining ($r$): $P_{pre-game}*r + P_{in-game}*(1-r)$

Comment: I considered that, it works ok but if say pregame was 45% and live is also 45% (meaning they are losing slightly) then their win rate is still 45%. And when I compare to the popular models, they seem to always give a team lower than their starting chance if they are losing. Which to me just makes sense. So I think that if the live is 50% their chance should be same as pregame and if it is less than 50% their chance should be less than pregame. So then I tried P = (startP / .5 ) * liveP . The only problem is with high startP and liveP it can go over 1 probabilty.